# Firebase auth user null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have my onCreate in my LoginActivity like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser!= null) {
            currentUserId = currentUser.getUid();
        }
```

But my variable, when I install for the first time my app, currentUserId is null. why? how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I install for the first time my app, currentUserId is null... why?

That's the expected behavior since the user is not authenticated the first time it installs/opens the app. FirebaseAuth's [getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()) methods:

> Returns the currently signed-in [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) or **null** if there is none.

So as seen above, if you get null, the user is not authenticated. To get the actual FirebaseUser object, authenticate the user with [one of the available options/prividers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), and that object won't be null anymore.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i solved it, i was facing the problem because i did not get the variable after signing in with email and password authentication.